# Are there any benefits of using PgBouncer with Session pool mode vs default pooling from Entity Framework?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, connection-pooling, pgbouncer

I am currently migrating Postgresql installed on an Azure VM to Azure Postgres Flexible Server. One of the advantages is the ability to use PgBouncer, unfortunately in my case it is not possible to use Transaction pooling mode, due to the use of prepared statements.

Hence my question is, are there any advantages to using PgBouncer with pooling mode Session compared to using default pooling with Entity Framework?